# Angular Material: show menu icon when sidenav collapses

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using a sidenav that collapses when the window is smaller than 1280px by setting this: `md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')"`
But I would like that when it collapses a menu icon (Hamburger button) shows so that the menu can be displayed if the user clicks on it.
This is the html, and I haven't written any js.

Right now it behaves like the Sidenav left from [the demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav) at Angular Material.

```
<div id="menu-icon">
            <svg ng-click="showMenu()" fill="#FFFFFF" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                <path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <md-sidenav ng-cloak id="main-layout-sidebar" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" layout="column" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">

            <div ng-cloak class="user-options">
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="user-icon">
                        <md-icon class="picture" md-font-set="material-icons"> account_circle </md-icon>
                    </div>
                    <div id="user-info">
                        <p id="username">{{username}}</p>
                        <md-button ng-click="logout()">Cerrar sesión </md-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <md-list ng-cloak class="menu">
                <md-list-item ng-repeat="(name, uiref) in items" ng-class="{ active: $state.includes({{uiref}}) }">
                    <a ui-sref={{uiref}}>
                        <md-button class="sidebar-button">
                            {{name}}
                        </md-button>
                    </a>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
        </md-sidenav>
```

How could I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: You need js logic or html/css?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide whichever, I can change both things. I though maybe there was a way to do it with the angular material directives that I haven't found yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it *via jQuery* or *Angular way*.

### Via jQuery:

***Javascript***

```
$scope.isSidenavOpen = false;  
$scope.$watch('isSidenavOpen', function(isSidenavOpen) {
    if(isSidenavOpen){
        $('#yourButton').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#yourButton').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

***HTML***

```
<button id='yourButton'></button>
```

### Angular way:

***Javascript***

```
$scope.isSidenavOpen = false;
```

***HTML***

```
<button id='yourButton' ng-hide='isSidenavOpen'></button>
```

I didn't test this code, but it should work. As i remember, `ng-hide` doesn't require to add `$watch`.
Hope it's helpfull.

Comment: But how can I tell when the sidenav closes to update the boolean? The closing of the nav is done automatically thanks to this `md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')"`

Comment: As i remember, it's under the hood of angular material. I used this code fine, if i don't mistake, here is all that you need to add. About the boolean: it updates by the wather `$scope.$watch('isSidenavOpen', ...`

Comment: Did you copy the default angular code for sidenav from Angular Material site? It's necessary to make the upper code working https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav.  _(sorry for my english)_

Comment: It worked just fine by doing what you said. I just didn't understood why. Thanks!

Comment: @moondaisy Happy to help!